# OneSignal-node Android doesn't receive additionnalData properties

Tags: android, node.js, onesignal, node-mysql

Here's the thing. I want to send a push notification to an android device using OneSignal from a node.js server which takes data from a mysql database to send them as **additionalData** on the notification.

I use **onesignal-node** module to send the notification and **node-mysql** for retreiveing the datas from the database.

I end up with a code like this

```
const notification = new OneSignal.Notification({
    headings: { en: "Notification heading" },
    contents: { en: "Dude, you gotta a notification" },
    include_external_user_ids: some_external_ids
});
notification.postBody["data"] = {
    foo: result[0],
    bar: result[1]
};
osClient.sendNotification(notification, (error, response, data) => {
    if(error) console.log(error);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

where **result** is the result of a query through **node-mysql**

Now the problem is that either the mobile app receives the **additionalData** (**notification.postBody["data"]**) as an empty object or as a JSONobject that has "foo" and "bar" properties but their values are empty.

I can't figure out why.